# File upload utility

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, image-upload, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm trying to implement a basic file, image upload utility into a small, simple (built using the Visual Web Developer tutorial) C# MVC3 ASP.Net web site. I have see this utility pointed out here on StackOverFlow a few times:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

...but unsure if I can just slot it into my MVC3 C# Website? (I am very new to attempting to learn MVC3 with C#).

I also see lots of this guides floated around the place:

- http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash
- http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax
- http://tomas.epineer.se/archives/3

Can any of these simply be slotted into my website?
Appreciate any help

Comment: Yes, it looks like any of those would fit well with MVC.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What difficulties did you encounter? Currently it is not quite clear what you expect from us.

Comment: Have you looked at http://imageresizing.net/? If you need any on-the-fly or during-upload processing, it's ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The first two seem to fit perfectly.